# What type of JSON data does DRF want?

Tags: django, rest, vue.js, frameworks, serialization

I am using Vuejs and Django for my web app. Vuejs is responsible for sending all requests (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE) through axios.

```
submitContact() {
  const {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    hp_no,
    twitter,
    github,
    company
  } = this

  axios.post(this.apiUrl, {
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    hp_no,
    twitter,
    github,
    company,
  })
  .then()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

This function is called when the form is submitted.

For handling POST data in views:

```
def contact_data(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():   # When user is authenticated
    if request.method == 'GET':         # For viewing records
        contacts = Contact.objects.all().filter(user=request.user.id)
        contacts_serialized = ContactSerializer(contacts, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(contacts_serialized.data, safe=False,)
    elif request.method == 'POST':      # For creating a record
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(json_data)
        serializer = ContactSerializer(data=json_data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':    # For deleting a record
        pass
else: # When user is not authenticated 
    return HttpResponse("You are not authorized to access!")
```

Currently, When I am making a form submission, the view is getting a JSON POST Response like this:

```
{'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'email': 'jane@gmail.com', 'hp_no': '0111634859', 'twitter': 'jane93', 'github': 'jane23', 'company': 'Jane ltd'}
```

But the serializer is taking it as an invalid serialized data and returning an 400 response. What might be the step I am missing here?

Comment: The data returned in 400 response is what?

Comment: 400 bad request, which means the JSON data it is getting in POST request is invalid or in other way, serializer.is_valid() method is not getting executed.

Comment: `print(request.data)` before `json_data = json.loads(request.body) `

Comment: It is sending an error

    AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: In this case the error should be in vue

Comment: I see you are passing `serializer.errors` to the 400 Response; can you tell us what's inside that dict?

Comment: This is something that serializer.errors returned. {'non_field_errors': ['Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got generator.']}

I didn't have a clue to print it out before you told me. I guess, i got a lead now. Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem is solved, I had to add a dictionary value 'user': <user_id> into the view.